# jeditable not updating browser display - leaves "click to edit..." after succesful edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I am using jeditable fairly simply and it all works fine, updates the database, etc. The only problem I have is after the user types the new value data and hits enter
it doesn't update the field in the browser to show the new value - instead it puts "Click to edit..." in place of it.

Am I missing something like a return value from my php file? The php function just takes the args and updates the database - and it works fine.

The jquery\jeditable code

```
$('.edit').editable('update.php',{
   id: 'field',
   name: 'val',
   indicator: 'Saving...',
   tooltip: 'Click to edit...',
   select : true,
   submitdata : { db : "pers", kn : "key", rec : "?php echo $rec; ?" }
});
```

the div

```
<div class="edit" id="svc_ad1"><?php echo $row->svc_ad1; ?></div>
```

I also have a css class for pEdit

```
edit{    
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:15px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing like answering your questions... anyhow I figured out I was missing this from my php file:

```
print $_POST['val'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your saving script needs to return the value you want Jeditable to display. If you're not returning anything from the saving script, then you'll get the default 'Click to edit'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps know what the javascript variable for the edited field is?